# Why is this finite difference operator nonnegative?

Tags: functional-analysis, numerical-methods

If a mesh function is given by $\Psi_i=|\Phi_0|+\max_{0\leq j\leq N}|L^N_\epsilon\Phi_j|+\Phi_i$ for any mesh function $\Phi$.

I know that $\Psi_0\geq 0$ but cannot figure out why $L^N_\epsilon\Psi_i\geq 0$. Here the operator is defined as $L^N_\epsilon=\epsilon D^-+I$, where $D^-V_i=(V_i-V_{i-1})/h_i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $\Psi$ is $\Phi$ plus some constant  $C$ (namely, $C=|\Phi_0|+\max_{0\leq j\leq N}|L^N_\epsilon\Phi_j|$). Therefore, $D^- \Psi_i = D^- \Phi_i$ and 
$$L_\epsilon^N \Psi_i =L_\epsilon^N \Phi_i + C$$
The value of $C$ was chosen to beat all  $L_\epsilon^N \Phi_i$, thus making the sum nonnegative.